# Hiding actionbar button from expandable list view adapter of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistadapter

I have an activity which consists of fragment view pager. Each fragment consists of an expandable listview. I want to show or hide the actionbar button from the expandable listview adapter. I tried it by passing the menu item to the adapter class but its not working. Cant able to show or hide the button from adapter class. Can anyone help me to obtain this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a hide/show function in your Activity class that has access to your MenuItem(I am assuming you are inflating it there).

```
    MenuItem buttonToShowHide;
    ....................//rest of your activity code
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mainmenu, menu);
        //Initialize your menuitem here: 
        buttonToShowHide=menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_id);
        return true;
}
//Now you can make a function that will show/hide your menu item
public void setButtonVisibility(boolean visible){
  //show item 
  buttonToShowHide.setVisibility(visible);
  invalidateOptionsMenu(); //invalidate the menu
}
```

Now you can get your activity instance inside your adapter class easily using context.You can then use the above function to show/hide your menu item.

```
    MyActivity myActivity=(MyActivity) context;
    //now you can access the above function as:
   myActivity.setButtonVisibility(true);
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jonDoe. I tried the same but instead of activity I have to use the function in fragment. How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you inflating your menu ? In fragment or in your Activity?

Comment: As fragment is the child of view pager, I am inflating it in fragment. The actionbar button show and hide should happen according to the viewpager's child data.

Comment: you can make similar function in your fragment and then call the function inside your adapter easily.